# Transaction like implementation of promises library for front-end

Tags: javascript, transactions, promise

I have pretty complex logic on front-end for saving files to server:

```
1) Save file1
2) Save file2
3) Save file3
```

If file3 fails to save, file2 and file1 have to be reverted. Right now I'm using promises:

```
file1.save().then(file2.save).then(file3.save).
```

I just thought that there could be an implemenation for these cases sort of like transactions for database. Is there anything like that?

Comment: file1.save().then(file2.save).then(file3.save, function(err){ /*revert file1, file2 save coz file3 failed to save*/});

Comment: @Lekhnath: Uh, [no](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)

Comment: @Maximus: How do can your "revert" a file? Do your file objects have a `revert` method or so?

Comment: @Bergi, yeah, it's possible to implement revert method for it

Answer (score 1):

what you need is some sort of endpoint in server to revert, I am going to leave the logic of that implementation to you, just using stubs `file.save()` for save and `file.revert()` for reverting, and assuming that both return promises:

```
var files = [file1, file2, file3, ...], revertFiles =[];
var promise = Promise.resolve();
files.forEach( file => 
    promise.then(() => file.save())
        .then(() => revertFiles.unshift(file))
);
promise.catch(e => revertFiles.forEach( file => promise.then( () => file.revert() )));
```

basically, whenever you finish some action, make a stack of actions for reverting that, and when you face some failure, just do all the actions stacked up in the queue.

**Edit**: in es5 style

```
var files = [file1, file2, file3, ...], revertFiles =[];
var promise = Promise.resolve();

files.forEach(function(file){
  promise.then(function(){
    return file.save();
  }).then(function(){
    revertFiles.unshift(file);
  });
});

promise.catch(function(e){
  revertFiles.forEach(function(file){
    promise.then(function(){
      return file.revert();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, I was actually asking about some sort of library, but your comment may be insightful as well. Can you rewrite your example in javascript?